# gdb set variable to string with hex values

Tags: c, gdb

```
set argv[0] = "\x01\x02\x03"
print argv[0]
results in "x01x02x03"
```

What?

show language is c, setting just a character seems to work.

GNU gdb 6.3.50

Apparently it works in 7.3, guess its not an option then.

Comment: What version of gdb? seems to work on 7.3.

Comment: I can verify the behaviour described in the question with the GDB provided with Mac OS X 10.7.5 (which is `GDB gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1822) (Sun Aug  5 03:00:42 UTC 2012)`), but it is good to know that it is fixed in 7.3.

Comment: Note that setting strings is dangerous, even if it seems to work. `gdb` is probably overwriting the storage allocated for the current value, and that will only work safely as long as the new value is not longer.